# Is there a way to tell if an IIS site is connected to SharePoint?

Tags: 2007, iis, powershell

I'd like to run a script report back what IIS Sites are SharePoint and which ones are normal sites.

Using the following command in powershell, I get a long list of properties of the application pool, but there is no uniqueness between what sites are SharePoint sites and which ones are not.

```
get-wmiobject -class IISApplicationPoolSetting -namespace "root\microsoftiisv2"
              -computername $server -authentication 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the virtual directories via IIS. There should be some pointing to /_layouts/, /_controltemplates/, /_vti_bin/, etc. These all point to the physical "Sharepoint root" folders (C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14)

Answer (score 1):

Your SharePoint sites *may* all be running under an appropriate application pool identity, separate from any other IIS site on your environment.